# Avoiding autoreleased objects, good practice or overkill?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-management

I am just curious with regards to the following, when I am writing code I always try and manage the memory myself by sticking to non-autoreleased objects. I know that this means that objects are not hanging around in the pool, but I was just curious if doing it this way in general is good practice or simply overkill?

```
// User Managed Memory
NSSet *buttonSizes = [[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects:@"Go", @"Going", @"Gone", nil];
[barItemLeft setPossibleTitles:buttonSizes];
[barItemRight setPossibleTitles:buttonSizes];
[buttonSizes release];
```

.

```
// Autoreleased Memory
NSSet *buttonSizes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"Go", @"Going", @"Gone", nil];
[barItemLeft setPossibleTitles:buttonSizes];
[barItemRight setPossibleTitles:buttonSizes];
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Total overkill.  If you read the relevant documentation carefully, it does not say that you should avoid autoreleasing objects.  It says that you should avoid using autorelease pools when you in tight, object-rich loops.  In those cases, you should be managing your memory explicitly (with `retain` and `release`) to ensure that objects are created and destroyed in an amortized manner.

The argument that the iPhone is a memory-constrained environment is true, but a *complete* red herring.  Objective-C, with the Foundation and Cocoa frameworks (though they weren't called that at the time), ran *just fine* on a NeXTcube, which had 16MB of RAM (expandable to 64).  Even the iPhone 3, which is pretty much EOL at this point, has 128MB.

**edit**

Since an iPhone app is a runloop-based application, a new autorelease pool is going to be created and destroyed every time it spins.  This is clearly defined in the documentation.  As such, the only reasons you'd have to create your own autorelease pool are:

- Spawning a background thread, where you *must* create your own pool (since new threads, by default, do not have a base ARPool)
- Performing some operation that will generate a significant number of autoreleased objects.  In this case, creating and draining a pool would be to help ensure the limited lifetime of the temporary objects.

However, in the second case, you're recommended to explicitly manage memory as much as possible.  This is so that your operation doesn't come to a screeching halt when it attempts to drain a pool with a few thousand objects in it.  If you manage your memory manually, you can release these objects gradually as they are no longer needed, instead of saving them up for a single all-at-once release.  You could help amortize the all-at-once release by nesting ARPools, which will help.

At the end of the day, though, just do what feels natural, and then (and *only* then) optimize it if you have concrete evidence that you need to do so.

**edit #2**

OK, it turns out that there *is* a [recommendation to avoid using `autorelease`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/Performance/Performance.html).  **BUT** that recommendation is in the "Allocate Memory Wisely" section of the "Tuning for Performance and Responsiveness" area of the iOS Application Programming Guide.  In other words, avoid it *if you're measuring a performance problem*.  But seriously: autorelease has been around for ~20 years and did just fine on computers far slower and more constrained than the iDevices of today.

Comment: Although the iPhone does have upwards of 128 MB of ram applications will typically only be able to access 20 MB before it starts getting warnings. Given that it doesn't support paging, I think that memory-constraints can be an issue for some applications (although almost always a solvable issue).

Comment: @Kevin Sure, but even 20MB is more than a stock cube had.  Granted that an iPhone app will have more resources loaded into memory, the point is that excessively autoreleasing objects will not kill your app, unless you're creating thousands of them in a tight loop.  Editing answer for clarification.

Comment: Thank you Dave for an excellent answer, I just wanted to check which way was the preferred method (and why), much appreciated.

Comment: Although I agree with your point that autorelease is fine in the general case, you're underestimating the RAM constraints here just a little. The Cube came with a minimum 64 MB of RAM. As far as I can tell, the last Mac to ship with 20 MB or less was the PowerBook 5300 in 1995.

Comment: @Chuck not the G4 cube, the NeXTcube; my point is that if Objective-C and NeXTStep could run just fine on that hardware, then it'll run just fine on an iPhone.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you see performance issues (or memory issues), I wouldn't worry about using the autorelease pools. Furthermore, autorelease in theory can be more performant than non-auto release. The really dangerous places to use autorelease is in large loops (for example, when importing a large data set). In these cases you can run out of the limited iPhone memory.

I'd recommend you only focus on removing autorelease usage once you've finished your application and can identify memory management issues using the built in instruments.

Answer (score 2):

When possible I like to use the autorelease methods.  It eliminates the chance that I forget to release them or somebody comes in and changes the flow of the code so that the explicit release is bypassed.  I vote that self-managing the releases is overkill.

Answer (score 1):

There's a balance. It depends a lot on the situation. In that particular case, assuming the `barItem*` variables are long-lived ivars, avoiding autorelease is pretty close to 100% pointless, because the set will be sticking around regardless of whether you release it now or two seconds from now.

In fact, in most cases, it makes little difference whether objects are released now or on the next iteration of the runloop, because the runloop is going so fast that it's actually capable of creating *smooth animation*. The iPhone is a particularly memory-starved platform, so it's good not to leave things alive too long. But at the same time, be realistic: One autoreleased NSNumber in a method that's called every couple of seconds isn't even going to make a dent in your app's profile. Even 100 thousand-character NSStrings will only use about 0.065% of the system RAM on an iPhone 3GS. That only becomes significant when you build up a ton of them in a very short time. So if there's no problem, don't sweat it.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether or not an autorelease pool is in place. For instance, if you're using objective-c objects in an AudioUnit's render callback (which is called from a separate thread without an autorelease pool) your autoreleased objects will leak. In this case it's important that you release them manually, or wrap them in an autorelease pool.

In general though, I think it's up to you and your coding style

Comment: I also have to add that sometimes it is impossible to avoid autoreleased objects, as the Cocoa framework uses them itself, in property getters, NSString class methods, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is only one resonable answer: usually autorelease is not an performance issue. It is good to keep in mind that it could be problematic in tight loops, but unless a performance meter like Instruments shows a memory spike you have to get rid of, I would use it if you like.

Premature optimization is a great way of spending time for nothing. Maybe in the end you know that your  solution is elegant, but it could be that the easier solution performs just as fine.